# Expected an identifier and ')'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomCard(
      onTap: null,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      child: OpenContainer(
        transitionType: ContainerTransitionType.fadeThrough,
        openBuilder: (BuildContext context, VoidCallback _) {
          return ViewImage(post: post);
        },
        closedElevation: 0.0,
        closedShape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(10.0),
          ),
        ),
        onClosed: (v) {},
        closedColor: Theme.of(context).cardColor,
        closedBuilder: (BuildContext context, VoidCallback openContainer) {
          return Stack(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(10.0),
                    ),
                    child:
                    
                     **final** fileName = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailFile({
    video: "https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4",
    thumbnailPath: (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,
    imageFormat: ImageFormat.WEBP,
    maxHeight: 64,
    quality: 75,
});
         ),
```

This is my code and the code before, I've got the error at the word final. So the console gives me an error. And says that it expected an indentifier and a ')' around the word final, but I don't know were exactly I have to place it. Is there anyone who can help me with this problem? I don't know if the error is being caused by the earlier code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you are missing a widget as child property

Answer (score 0):

I believe I can see a couple of issues here:

1. You're missing the braces `{` and `}` for your properties.
2. You should remove trailing commas `,` from your property list, otherwise it may cause issues in some browsers.

Try the following instead:

```
VideoThumbnail.thumbnailFile({
    video: "https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4",
    thumbnailPath: (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,
    imageFormat: ImageFormat.WEBP,
    maxHeight: 64,
    quality: 75
});
```

Comment: doesn't work for me, the error is still at the word final

Comment: I guess I read the title before you finished editing your question, as that gives a completely different error message ;)
I think we'll need to see more of the surrounding code before we can give an appropriate answer.

Comment: I've editted the code so I hope you can see the problem now

Comment: I see now that you're using dart. As mentioned in the other answer, you're declaring a variable when trying to assign it to `child`. Try moving it out into another location. If that helps, then you should accept the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

You declare a var in a child property; this is your problem.

Your code :

```
final fileName = await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailFile({
    video: "https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4",
    thumbnailPath: (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,
    imageFormat: ImageFormat.WEBP,
    maxHeight: 64,
    quality: 75,
});
```

should be declared in the right place, so for example in a `setState` function.